# Hide PhoneGap ChildBrowser buttons

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I'm developping a PhoneGap app.

I use the ChildBrowser plugin for iOS but there are ugly buttons I'd like to hide:
- "Done" button
- Back & forward button
- Refresh button
- Open in Safari button
If it it possible, I'd like to completely remove this footerbar.

I think you've already asked yourself the question! I'm not used to Objective C and I don't find the solution..

Thank you

Comment: For those who look for the solution, you just have to edit the xib file, remove the footerbar and resize the uiWebView. Hope this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

use parameters on .showWebPage(), check out [this link](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/09/phonegap-android-childbrowser-revamp.html).